# Is there any commercial vector technology platform for boosting recombinant protein production?

Tags: proteins, plasmids, recombinant, vector

I am a novice in biomedical industry. Our team would like to search new vector technology for boosting recombinant protein production. It's difficult to google a firm that provide those plasmids.

Dose anyone know if one exists?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "new vector technology"? Vectors to transfect cells in order to have them produce proteins isn't exactly a new technology. Also: Which kind of protein (posttranslationally modified or not), which kind of cells?

Comment: Sorry for the misdescription. I mean engineered vector, such as ProteoNic 2G UNic™ technology platform, to product mAbs in CHO cells.

Comment: Why is it so hard to Google this topic? I'm sure there are guides out there to help people decide which expression system might be best for them.